# How to control two UIScrollViews in the same time with one touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

Anyone has an idea how to control two scroll views while one in on the top of the other. One scrolls, the other one scrolls too. Same with zoom, gesture recognisers, etc ... Kinda like passing replica of the touches received by the first view onto the the one underneath. Subclass of the top scroll view has got a weak reference to the "dependant" scroll view underneath. Very important is to get the delegate methods working for both scrollviews as there is a lot of logic in these ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the scrollView Delegate methood

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  if([scrollView isEqual:scrollViewA]) {
    CGPoint offset = scrollViewB.contentOffset;
    offset.y = scrollViewA.contentOffset.y;
    [scrollViewB setContentOffset:offset];
  } else {
    CGPoint offset = scrollViewA.contentOffset;
    offset.y = scrollViewB.contentOffset.y;
    [scrollViewA setContentOffset:offset];
  }
}
```

or simply in the same method for both horizontal an vertical scrolling

```
 if([scrollView isEqual:scrollViewA]) {
scrollViewB.contentOffset = scrollViewA.contentOffset;
}
```

and viceVersa